# Render status and data JSON response with active model serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, active-model-serializers

I'm using active model serialiser.

I want to render both 'status' and 'data' in JSON format, e.g.

```
{"status":"success","data":[{"id":1,"content":xxx"}]}
```

I've been able to produce the 'data' using the following code in my rails controller:

```
@jobs = Job.all
render json: @jobs
```

How can I render both 'status' and 'data'? I've tried doing:

```
@jobs = Job.all
render :json => { :status => :success, :data => @jobs }
```

This doesn't recognize my JobSerializer, so renders JSON output, but not with the attributes and associations specified in my JobSerializer.

I've also tried:

```
@jobs = Job.all
render :json => { :status => :success, :data => ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@jobs, each_serializer: JobSerializer) }
```

This appears to work,  i.e. renders a JSON response with the right attributes speicified in my JobSerializer, but doesn't recognise or render the associations in my JobSerializer (i.e. a has_many association)

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: `def send_data
  @jobs.each do |job|
    job.data
    job.status
  end
  render something, json: @jobs.as_json  
end` try defining this method..hope this helps..

Comment: Sorry not sure what this is trying to achieve? what will doing job.data and job.status on each job do?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like:

```
render :json => {
    status: "success",
    data: ContentSerializer.new( contents ).attributes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@jobs = Job.all
render json: @jobs, status: 200
```

if above dosent work try this one

```
@jobs = Job.all
render json: @jobs, status: 200, serializer: JobSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to render on this way:

```
@jobs = Job.all
render :json => { :status => :success, :data => @jobs.to_json }
```

**UPDATE:**

if you want to render and related objects, this should look like:

```
render :json => { :status => :success, :data => @jobs.to_json(:include => :users) }
```

here I assumed that the `job` model has `users`

Comment: didn't work unfortunately. renders a JSON response, but doesn't recognise the attributes or associations in JobSerialize.

Comment: Yeah but this is just manually loading in the association - @jobs still doesn't recognise the attributes and associations I've already specified in JobSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add attr_accessor to your model class

   class Job < ApplicationRecord
        attr_accessor :status

   end

2.Then add same attribute to your serilizer

```
 class JobSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :address, :email,:status
  has_one :branch
 end
```

3.Done add code like this in your controller

@job.status = 'success'
        render json: @job, status: 200

Answer (score 0):

`@jobs = Job.all
render :json => { :status => :success, :data => (ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(@jobs, each_serializer: JobSerializer))`

For `has_many` association to work, the association needs to be defined in both the model and serializer

`class JobSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer`

        `has_many :association`

 `end`

`class Section < ApplicationRecord`

        `has_many :association`

 `end`